# Does mybatis support check property exist?

Tags: mybatis

I want to dynamically construct sql with different concrete subclass

```
List<CommonDO> commonQuery(AbstractQuery query)
```

but if property not exists it will throw exception like below

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'foo' in 'class ...'
```

So is there some manner could avoid this, e.g. check property exists first

```
    <if test="foo">
        ... 
    </if>
```

Comment: The closest is `<if test="_parameter['foo'] != null">`. Note that it returns false when the property exists and its value is null.

Comment: `Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: com.xx.Query.foo`

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, I guess. You should probably check the runtime class name like `<if test="_parameter.class.name == 'com.xx.Query'">`. If you really need to check property existence, you may be able to define a static method `public static boolean propertyExists(Object param, String property)` which uses reflection and use it like `<if test="@com.xx.MapperUtil@propertyExists(_parameter, 'foo')">`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems check if a property exists in a parameter type is not simple

Answer (score 0):

Checking property existence is not easy, however, you can check the parameter type instead.

Assuming that there are two subclasses of `AbstractQuery`...

```java
public class QueryChild1 extends AbstractQuery {
  private String foo;

  // getter/setter
}

public class QueryChild2 extends AbstractQuery {
  private Integer bar;

  // getter/setter
}
```

You can check the parameter type before evaluating the property value to avoid the exception.

```xml
<select ...>
  select ...
  <where>
    <if test="_parameter instanceof x.y.QueryChild1 and foo != null">
      and col_foo = #{foo}
    </if>
    <if test="_parameter instanceof x.y.QueryChild2 and bar != null">
      and col_bar = #{bar}
    </if>
  </where>  
</select>
```

In the comment, I shared a few different ways to check the parameter type, but using `instanceof` may be better than the alternatives.

---

p.s.
It's an old question, but I have seen several similar questions, so it may be worth a proper answer.