# Using SpringBoot2.7 and MyBatis 2.3 How can I code a cleaner request class structure?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, inheritance, mybatis

First of all I apologize for my poor English skills.

So far, when designing a class that receives a request from a form, I have created each class separately.

This time, unlike before, we are trying to design a request class using inheritance.

This is my request classes and controller.

```
// super class
public abstract class MenuRequest {

    
    private String beginDate;
    
    private String endDate;
    
    private Integer restaurantId;
    
    private Integer mealId;

}

// sub class1
public class MenuListRequest extends MenuRequest{

    private Integer ingredientLook;
    private Integer currentPage;
    private Integer listCountPerPage;
}

// sub class2
public class MenuTableRequest extends MenuRequest {

}

// controller 1
@Controller
public class MenuListController {

    @Autowired
    private MenuListServiceImpl menuListServiceImpl;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String getList(MenuListRequest menuListRequest, Model model) {
        ...
    }

}

@Controller
public class MenuTableController {
    
    @Autowired
    private MenuTableServiceImpl menuTableServiceImpl;
    
    @GetMapping("/table")
    public String getTable(Model model, MenuTableRequest menuTableRequest) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And the mapper class and xml file are like this.

```
@Mapper
public interface MenuMapper {

    public List<Menu> selectMenuList(MenuRequest menuRequest);

}


// code in xml
<select id="selectMenuList" resultType="com.sikdan.ojt.model.vo.Menu">

        SELECT date_format(ymd, '%Y-%m-%d') AS ymd, restaurant_nm, meal_nm, food_nm, ingredients_nm
        FROM cms_menu AS m
        LEFT JOIN cms_restaurant AS r
        ON m.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id
        LEFT JOIN cms_meal_division AS md
        ON m.meal_id = md.meal_id
        LEFT JOIN cms_food AS f
        ON m.food_id = f.food_id
        <choose>
            <when test='ingredientLook == 2'>
                LEFT JOIN
                (
                SELECT food_id, group_concat(ingredients_nm) AS ingredients_nm
                FROM cms_recipe AS rc
                LEFT JOIN cms_ingredients AS i
                ON
                rc.ingredients_id = i.ingredients_id
                GROUP BY food_id
                ) AS i
                ON m.food_id = i.food_id
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                RIGHT JOIN cms_recipe AS rc
                ON m.food_id = rc.food_id
                LEFT JOIN cms_ingredients AS i
                ON rc.ingredients_id = i.ingredients_id
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        WHERE ymd BETWEEN #{beginDate} AND #{endDate}
        <if test='restaurantId != null'>
            AND m.restaurant_id = #{restaurantId}
        </if>
        <if test='mealId != null'>
            AND m.meal_id = #{mealId}
        </if>
        ORDER BY ymd,
        m.restaurant_id,
        m.meal_id,
        m.food_id
        <if test='ingredientLook != 2'>
            ,rc.ingredients_id
        </if>
        <if test='listCountPerPage != null'>
            LIMIT #{currentPage}, #{listCountPerPage}
        </if>
</select>
```

The reason I wrote the code like this is because the type of List needed in the service is the same.
However, the class returned to the controller in the service stage after request is different.

Someone might have predicted it, but the '' part was a problem and an error occurred. This seems to be because MenuTableRequest does not have a member variable called ingredientLook.

I think there are two ways to solve this problem.

1. It is not used in the MenuTableRequest class, but it is always treated as null by putting a variable called IngredientLook.
2. Using separate methods in Mapper without using inheritance.

I'm wondering which of these is the better way. Or just wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks for reading.

Since different forms call the list of same VO class, I tried to solve both tasks through one Mapper method by designing a request class through inheritance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76842401/1261766) helps.